# Positional argument after keyword argument and regular parameter after * parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to use Python 2.7 and I'm running into an issue that I wasn't having in Python 3.

```
def foo(*dirs, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=False, arg6=False):
```

I'd call the function like so:

```
foo('folder_name', arg2=100, arg3=['string', 'string2'], arg4='test6', arg5=True, arg6=False)
```

But I get an error message saying:

```
                     def foo(*dirs, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=False, arg6=False):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the definition of the function I can see it says `regular parameter after * parameter`. I did some research and can see `*dirs` has to be the last parameters specified.

So I can change the function parameters to this:

```
def foo(arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=False, arg6=False, *dirs):
```

However, when I do this I then get an error message saying:
`SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Does anyone know a way to resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what about `def foo(arg2,  *dirs, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=False, arg6=False,):`

Comment: Neither of those work, unfortunately. I still get the message `regular parameter after * parameter`

Comment: Add default value to `arg2` in the definition, then arg2 has to be used as a keyword argument (which you do anyways) but the order will be ok. | Also, fyi, support for Python2.7 was dropped a week ago.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` when I call `foo` at the end of the call where `*dirs` is I call it like so: `foo(arg2=15, arg3=['hello there'], arg4='test', arg5=True, arg6=False, 'folder_name'). Not sure why I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `dirs` parameter specifies *one* argument (positional or keyword) for `foo`, e.g. *one* string or *one* list of strings, in other words IF you intend to call `foo` like:

```
foo("folder_name", other args)
```

or

```
foo(["folder_name1", "folder_name2, ...], other args)
```

then you don't need to prepend its name with `*`, and the "workaround" of your answer is actually the way to go. See also: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions .

But if `dirs` specifies an arbitrary sequence of arguments and you want to be able to do something like:

```
foo(other args, "folder_name1", "folder_name2",...)
```

there is a difference between python 2 and python 3, as you describe in your question. As you can see https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-parameter versus https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter , in Python3 there are *keyword-only* parameters:

> Keyword-only parameters can be defined by including a single var-positional parameter or bare * in the parameter list of the function definition before them

That's why in Python3 you didn't have problem defining foo as:

```
def foo(*dirs, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=False, arg6=False):
```

and calling it like:

```
foo('folder_name', arg2=100, arg3=['string', 'string2'], arg4='test6', arg5=True, arg6=False)
```

Notice, that in the call, you correctly provided all args after `"folder_name"` (even `arg2`) as keyword arguments, and so worked in Python3.

But in Python2, there are no keyword-only parameters. So, as you mention, you cannot have neither `regular parameter after * parameter` nor `non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. That's why even if you leave `*dirs` last in the parameter list, you cannot call `foo` supplying the previous arguments as keyword ones. What you could do, though, is to still leave `*dirs` last in the parameter list, and in the call to `foo` supply the previous args as positional. Example (python 2.7):

```
def bar(a=1, b=2, *c):   # see below
    return (a, b, c)
bar(1, 2, 3)      # => (1, 2, (3,))
bar(1, b=3, 3)    # => Error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
bar(1, 2)         # => (1 2 ())
bar(1)            # => Error: bar() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So, as you can see, even though it lets you define bar with default values for a, b (see *positional-or-keyword* in links above), they are not used, i.e. a and b are positional (and required).

Lastly, also check these links from python2 documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists and https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, but am open to other ideas if anyone has any.

I changed `*dirs` in the function definition to a keyword argument `dirs=None` then when I call `foo(dirs='folder_name', other arguments)` works fine.